# MVC controller view binding

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Am new to MVC and am trying below scenario but am struck how to proceed.

In my webpage i have several section and each section has comments below it. and for fetching the comments i have written a function  inside the controller as below

```
public ActionResult ShowPreviousComments()
        {
            Comments com = new Comments();

            LstComments savedComments = new LstComments();

            ///Entity code here


            foreach (var item in comments)
            {
                com.comments = item.Comments;
                com.dTime = item.Time;

                savedComments.lstCommet.Add(com);

            }

            return View();
        }
```

and model data below so i can get the list in the view

```
public class Comments
    {
        public string comments { get; set; }

        public DateTime? dTime { get; set; }

        public int airPortId { get; set; }

    }

    public class  LstComments
    {
        public List<Comments> lstCommet { get; set; }
    }
```

My doubt is how i can hit the controller during the pageload for each sections ?

Sorry if it sounds silly or some error. Please post if i can do it in  a better way

Thanks

Comment: you mean, you want to show comments in a view, partialy, right?

Comment: not partially bcoz sections are rendered dynamically

Answer (score 4):

controller

```
public ActionResult ShowPreviousComments()
{
    Comments com = new Comments();
    LstComments savedComments = new LstComments();

    ///Entity code here


    foreach (var item in comments)
    {
        com.comments = item.Comments;
        com.dTime = item.Time;

        savedComments.lstCommet.Add(com);
    }

    return PartialView(savedComments);
}
```

View

```
@Html.Action("ShowPreviousComments", "SomeController")
```

**From My Perspective**

controller

```
public ActionResult ShowPreviousComments()
{
    // Entity code here
    // var comments = entity.comments;

    return PartialView(comments);
}
```

**Index.cshtml** (Main view that contains own contents and comments)

```
// some main view content

// main view comments...
@Html.Action("ShowPreviousComments", "SomeController")
```

**ShowPreviousComments.chtml** (partial view that hold the previous comments)

```
@model IEnumerable<comments>

<div class="comments_container>
    foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="comment_body">@item.Comments</div>
        <div class="comment_time">@item.Time</div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe U can try a script to call the controller on load of the sections of the view